# PHP - Get and compare row value from a different column for the same row

Tags: php

I'm attempting to edit a custom function and struggling to get the row value for a particular custom column ('rank_td') to compare against its other columns (rank_lw and rank_lm), all inside a HTML table.

Tried a fair few variations and can't get it going.

Any ideas?

```
function custom_value($cellValue, $dataColumnHeader, $rank_td_value) {

if($dataColumnHeader == "rank_lw" || $dataColumnHeader == 'rank_lm'){

    $row['rank_td']->$cellValue = $rank_td_value;

    if($rank_td_value == $cellValue){
                $styleColor = 'color:blue;';
             }else if($rank_td_value < $cellValue){ 
                $styleColor = 'color:green;';
             }else{
                $styleColor = 'color:red;';
             } 
        return $class_name.'<span style="'.$styleColor.'">'.$cellValue.'</span>';
}

return $cellValue; }
```

[image: Sample data]

Comment: ````$row['rank_td']->$cel.. ```` etc looks like it doesn't belong here - what is it doing? Also ````$class_name```` is not defined I think.  Also it seems to be working in some of the cases, if I understand your code then only F:6, .and G:8/9 are wrong, so my suspicion would be an error calling the function rather than the function itself - in any case it would probably be helpful to see how it's implemented to help understand it

Comment: The issue is that line and I've tried a fair amount of different approaches to try to get the value. This code was originally working using a global rowIndex variable (i.e. if($wdtRowIndex == $cellValue) - It also works with the global $idval). I have to change it to rank_td as the rowindex isn't suitable to compare against when a filter is applied to the table. The coloring logic is all fine and the sample image above is the expected output (there are no issues as per your comment).

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the global variable `$row` which exists outside the scope of this function - hence my comment that it doesn't look like it belongs here.  If you want to be able to access a variable from outside a function you need to either pass that variable in, or declare it using the global keyword.  Here is a very basic example of this:

```
$row['some_value'] = "value1";

function scopeTest($var1) {
    $row['some_value'] = $var1;//local variable $row created
}
function scopeTestTwo($var1) {
    global $row;//variable outside the function
    $row['some_value'] = $var1;
}

scopeTest("jam");
print_r($row);//Array ( [some_value] => value1 )
scopeTestTwo("jam");
print_r($row);//Array ( [some_value] => jam )
```

in your code you also have this

```
return $class_name.'<span....
```

but `$classname` is not defined so either it is redundant and you should remove it (because this will cause a php notice and anyway redundant code is, well, redundant) or it should be defined somewhere which means something has been missed out

Comment: thanks for the example however I've managed to get the column by using if($cellValue['rank_td'] == ...). I should have mentioned that this function is a hook into a WP plugin so $class_name is embedded. With all that said however, I have a new issue where $cellValue['rank_td'] only returns the first integer for the entire dataset across all rows (and is stripping out the second for some reason). It is not a data issue as I can return the $cellValue successfully outside of that if statement using if($dataColumnHeader == "rank_td"). I'm astounded by the tediousness on this.